# Modify C igraph shortest.path "weights" argument

Tags: c, igraph, shortest-path

Would I have to modify the C *igraph* source code to add an option to the `shortest.paths` argument: `weights` that if `weights=` some string other than 'weights', say 'new_weights', then compute the weight on the fly?

Python's NetworkX has this option, but igraph does not.  If I'm wrong on this, please let me know.

Comment: Is this R igraph? Or Python igraph?

Comment: I started out in R with a large edge-list file. I need a modified shortest path (SP) to find the SP between a pair of nodes in G1, where the weights are the SP in G2 (G2 has the nodes in G1 and more).  Thus I think that such modification needs to be done in the C code.  If I have to do that modification to the C src, then I can just work in C, since I don't know how to incorporate a modified C src into R, is it the wrong approach?  I noticed that if I have an edge-list with `long int` from 1 to 12 igraph c will add a node id 0 resulting in 12+1 ids, in this case 12 is my node and igraph's  id?